# How to change HTML markup structure using javascript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following markup in a page.

```
<div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
</div>
```

Is it possible to change this markup as following when the page is opened on 768px width and below :

```
<div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
</div>
```

I do not want to touch the `<div class="tm_center"><!-- content code--></div>`
All I want to do is just moving the `<div class="tm_left"><!-- left side bar code--></div>` between the other two divs when the page is opened in 768px width and below.

Can achieve this using java script / css?
If the java script is the solution will it work on mobiles?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: You can do both, Javascript by listening to window resize event ant actually moving the DOM, or CSS by simulating such behavior using relative positioning or the like and some `@media` selectors. Good luck

Comment: You can do this by using css media queries easily. 
@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

Comment: you can do as well using CSS, but won't recommend you to do that. better change the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try your best before asking these questions! However your ans is below!

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/woqisu/4/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
    var $detCenter = $(".tm_center").detach();
    $(".tm_left").before($detCenter);        
  }
});
```

Comment: great, as long it helps you : )

Comment: It is true that posters often mention what they have already tried, but is it a requirement?  Why imply that user3090610 hasn't already tried their best before asking the question?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Flexbox Order property?

You can change the order by adding display: flexbox to a container:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
   </div>
   <div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
   </div>
   <div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
   </div>
</div>
```

and then in CSS:

```
.container { display: flexbox }
.tm_center { flex-order: -1;}
```

Take care with prefixes and compatibility.